# unable to open a pdf file at specific page in Adobe Reader 11 using C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, adobe, adobe-reader

The below lines of code are used to open a PDF file at a particular page in C#. the code works absolutely fine for all the adobe version other than the latest, which is 11.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" C:\\Jack and Jill.pdf";
myProcess.Start();
```

Can some one please help me out and let know what is special with adobe reader 11. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The error is "There was an error opening this document. The file cannot be found." (THE FILE DOES EXIST)

P.S: I have uninstalled adobe 11 and installed adobe reader 10 and the code works absolutely fine then.

also the arguments when given from command line when Acrobat Reader 11 is installed works fine and opens PDF.

Comment: Is the process still called AcroRd32.exe?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @glace: yes the process is still called AcroRd32

Comment: Does that code work by manually running it in cmd?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: the error is "There was an error opening this document. The file cannot be found."

Comment: @Despertar: the code works fine while running in cmd

Comment: Can you just invoke a static Process.Start(filename,arguments) instead of creating an object? Process.Start("C:\\example.pdf", "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\");  See if that launches Adobe 11 or not.

Comment: @glace: I get the same error Glace by invoking without creating an object

Comment: @Saichand Ok. Stupid question... does the file you're trying to open actually exist in the location you're specifying?

Comment: What is the result if you only pass in the filename? \A and the filename?

Comment: @glace: its not a stupid question. the error sentence makes one think like that. But i can open the file from cmd using the same arguments.

Comment: @RyanGates: when I pass in only the file (ex: `Process.Start( _PDFFileName );`). it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure u dont have spaces in the name of the file. it works if it has spaces in all other  adobe readers but  adobe reader 11 dosent support that.

Hope this helps

Comment: The issue was because of the space I had in the file name. 

changed the below line 
`myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" C:\\Jack and Jill.pdf";`

to 

`myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" \"C:\\Jack and Jill.pdf\"";`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Parameters for Opening PDF Files](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAB&url=http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf&ei=xGn0UMOiH8i9igKV7YHQBw&usg=AFQjCNHQGP6HRmFUIRvjEkXy2TH4eLIxkQ&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.cGE), your arguments line should look like this:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2\" C:\\example.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file **C:\example.pdf** exist. This error occurs when there is no file.

```
string pdfPath = @"C:\example.pdf";

if (System.IO.File.Exists(pdfPath))
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
     myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe";
     myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" \"{0}\"", pdfPath);
     myProcess.Start();
}
```

Comment: the file does exist and it opens when i execute it from cmd

Answer (score 0):

Open Parameters for Reader 11 have changed or been removed.
Use Reader 10.
I have asked Adobe for information on Open parameters for reader 11 but had no response.